# loading files with dates into netezza

Tags: netezza

I'm trying to import text file into netezza. As simplifie example I use the file with one column.

File

```
01/04/2011
01/01/2099
01/01/2011
```

I have the table

```
create table test_data
(f date)
```

I try to load data by

```
insert into test_data
select * from 
EXTERNAL 'C:\\Temp\\dt.txt'
USING
(   
    DATESTYLE 'DMY'
    DATEDELIM '/'
    MAXERRORS 100000000000
    Y2BASE 2000
    ENCODING 'internal'
    REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC'
    delimiter '\t'
    CRINSTRING TRUE
    TRUNCSTRING TRUE
    CTRLCHARS TRUE
    IGNOREZERO TRUE
   -- ESCAPECHAR '\'
)
```

and I have no data in the table after insert. Do you have any ideas about reason?

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm answering a very stale question, but google puts this near the top of "netezza datestyle" so it should have a correct answer on it.

Your data file and test table  DDL are both fine.  The INSERT statement has a lot of parameters that you don't need.  The minimal syntax is:

```
insert into test_data
select * from 
EXTERNAL 'C:\\Temp\\dt.txt'
USING
(   
    DATESTYLE 'DMY'
    DATEDELIM '/'
    REMOTESOURCE ODBC -- note that you had this as a quoted string. Either should work
    LOGDIR 'C:\\Temp' -- as someone pointed out, this will give you log files to troubleshoot
);
```

I just tested this syntax with your example file, and the data loads and sorts correctly (e.g. it knows that 1/4/2011 is April 1 not Jan 4)  Valid datestyle values are ‘YMD’, ‘MDY’, ‘DMY’, ‘MONDY’. The default is 'YMD'

Your high maxerrors (without a LOGDIR) means that records are silently discarded on error.
Unless you need to account for bad data records, set MAXERRORS as low as possible (e.g. 1, to account for an optional header row)

Comment: This answer helped me a lot, I would like to add something because this seems to be one of the only questions relevant to this subject. If you're still getting an error after specifying the datestyle, it may be because of your time format as well. The default is 24 hour format, and if your timestamp is in a 12 hour format it won't work(and will give a rather unhelpful error unless you check the logs). To specify time format use "TimeStyle '12Hour'", removing double quotes of course. For more info search for "Netezza_data_loading_guide", it is VERY helpful.

Comment: Glad it helped, Demarini.  Thanks for adding the info about time formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your insert looks fine from a remotesource. The nzlog generated from the insert statement should be viewable. Can you paste the error you're receiving from the log?

Answer (score -3):

no need to use the using part in the query

correct example is:

insert into table_name   select * from  external C:\temp\dt.txt

this should load the data in the table without any issues