# Netezza imports csv as an empty table

Tags: csv, import, netezza

I am importing a CSV file into Netezza using the INSERT INTO command:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
    SELECT
        *
    FROM EXTERNAL 'C:\\file.csv'
    USING (
        REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC'
        DELIMITER ','
        MAXERRORS 100000
        SKIPROWS 1
        ESCAPECHAR '\'
    )
;
```

Netezza "succesfully" finishes the task, i.e. no mistakes come up. However, the data is not imported at all. Out of 1000 rows, only 100 are imported and none of them contain anything.

I followed the code found in [Netezza CSV load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447950/netezza-csv-load)

I have also tried to import the data via the external table and it failed again in the same manner.

Am I missing something, for example some crucial parameter? This procedure has worked without problems before. I don't think there is anything wrong with the csv file I'm trying to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the issue, it is explained in more detail in this thread:

[loading files with dates into netezza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987293/loading-files-with-dates-into-netezza)

The problem was with importing Date formats. 
The following two lines needed to be specified in the code:

DATESTYLE 'DMY'

DATEDELIM '.'

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link you provided I see two parameters that may be required. Also a slight format change that may make a difference.

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
SELECT * FROM 
EXTERNAL 'C:\\file.csv'
USING 
(
    DELIMITER ','
    MAXERRORS 100000
    SKIPROWS 1
    Y2BASE 2000
    ENCODING 'internal'
    REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC'
    ESCAPECHAR '\'
    QUOTEDVALUE 'DOUBLE'
)
```

IBM also has a Data Loading Guide that can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/files/form/anonymous/api/library/1b6a2624-dc86-4856-b4ed-cdda6bfdecda/document/40a12afd-31d4-4a4f-b8c6-25c65f7b8a02/media).

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Try adding the quoted double option line. It is used to instruct Netezza to place double quotes around column data. I modified the code above to reflect this change.

Comment: I have done so and nothing changes. I really don't get it.

Comment: You could try changing your ENCODING to UTF-8 in place of internal.  Has your editor changed?

Comment: Make sure that the order that your columns appear in the csv file matches the order of the columns in the table. It is not enough to just have the same column name association.

Comment: It just doesn't work. I have now managed to succesfully import the csv file manually via the Aginity Workbench Menu. It is really strange that the code for import does not work. Could it be because some of the columns in the table are left as empty?

Comment: "Make sure that the order that your columns appear in the csv file matches the order of the columns in the table. It is not enough to just have the same column name association. "
I think the order is correct. In any case, netezza should have returned an error message if it wasn't?

Comment: If you have empty columns that couild be the issue. You should insert the keyword NULL in these locations. IBM has a data loading guide that goes into more detail. I added a link to it up in the answer above.